# extract Object parameters to POJO

Tags: java, jpa

How is it possible to get the [0], ..., [4] parameter's values of the Object below ?

The Object you see below is a result from EntityManager.createNativeQuery().
I would like to use the values to create a POJO. I know I could use EntityManager.createNativeQuery("SQL Query", MyPOJO.class), but it returns POJO only with ID, all other variables are null?! and I am interested in how to get object's parameters.

It's not possible to cast returned object to MyPOJO, because MyPOJO is a JPA Entity with references to another JPA Entities, and the returned object contains only IDs of another JPA Entities.

[image: Object state]

Thank you!

Comment: Create namedquery on entity and then use EntityManager.createNamedQuery("queryName"); it return a POJO class

Comment: Thank you, but it is not what I am asking, and I need to use createNativeQuery();.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

Let nativeQuery to return me result as a List of Object[] and access the Object's values through index.

Here is my solution:

```java
List<Object[]> executeObjects = null;
Query query = mgr.createNativeQuery("SQL Query");
executeObjects = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();

for (Object[] object : executeObjects) {
    Long id = new Long((Integer) object[0]);
    Long id2 = new Long((Integer) object[1]);
    String desc = (String) object[2];
    ...
    ...
}
```